# How to set first child in Expandable list view always selected

Tags: android

hii all, please tell me how to set first child in expandable list view always selected..
Is there any property in Expandable list view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try listView.expandGroup(0); but you would have to check if that group exists first.

Comment: is there any possibility to change icon of expandable listview ?

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted. Also yes, you need to implement a custom group layout, and set the default icon to null. http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/09/expandablelistview-on-android.html

Comment: I am not able to remove Group header icon of Expandable listview,can anybody tell me how to set it to null .... :(

Comment: listView.setGroupIndicator(null);

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method

```
setSelectedChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean shouldExpandGroup)
```

of ExpandableListView

Comment: I haven't tried it ...may be it is not possible.If you find one plz inform :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method

```
setItemChecked(position_you_want, true);
```

**Example**

```
stockFilter_expandableListView.setItemChecked(1, true);
```